# C# executing oracle function. Returns numeric or value error. No specific error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, plsql, oracle11g

I am running into an issue when trying to call a function in my Oracle database from c#. I am running Oracle 11G.
The problem is that I am getting a `numeric or value error` but I can't find the source of the problem.
Also there is no details on the error. I am only getting `numeric or value error`. You can verify this in the error log below.

This is my Oracle function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION GENERATERESETCODE(
  UserID NUMBER,
  CodeLength NUMBER
)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
  GeneratedCode VARCHAR2(1000) := '';
  FoundRows NUMBER(11) := -1;
BEGIN
  WHILE TRUE LOOP
    GeneratedCode := RANDOMSTRING(CodeLength);

    BEGIN
      SELECT R.Code
      INTO FoundRows
      FROM RESETCODE R
      WHERE R.Code = GeneratedCode;
    EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      INSERT INTO ResetCode VALUES (UserID, GeneratedCode, SYSDATE + 1);

      EXIT;
    END;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN GeneratedCode;
END GENERATERESETCODE;
```

C# Code:

```
public string GenerateResetCode(int userid)
{
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connString))
    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("GenerateResetCode", conn))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("UserID", OracleDbType.Int32, userid, ParameterDirection.Input));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("CodeLength", OracleDbType.Int32, 25, ParameterDirection.Input));

        string rtrnValue = "";
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("GeneratedCode", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1000, rtrnValue, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue));

        ExecuteNonQuery(conn, command);

        return rtrnValue;
    }
}
```

That function `ExecuteNonQuery` simply opens the connection, runs ExecuteNonQuery on the command and then closes the connection again.

Lastly here is my detailed error log from c#:

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException was unhandled by user code
  DataSource=""
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  HResult=-2147467259
  IsRecoverable=false
  Message=ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_RANDOM", line 173
ORA-06512: at "THOM.RANDOMSTRING", line 6
ORA-06512: at "THOM.GENERATERESETCODE", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 1
  Number=6502
  Procedure=""
  Source=Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver
  StackTrace:
       bij OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.VerifyExecution(OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
       bij OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.VerifyExecution(OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
       bij OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean isFromEF)
       bij Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       bij Libra.Repository.OracleDataContext.ExecuteNonQuery(OracleConnection conn, OracleCommand command) in C:\Users\thomv\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Libra\Libra\Repository\OracleDataContext.cs:regel 260
       bij Libra.Repository.OracleDataContext.GenerateResetCode(Int32 userid) in C:\Users\thomv\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Libra\Libra\Repository\OracleDataContext.cs:regel 75
       bij Libra.Controllers.DagboekController.StuurSupport() in C:\Users\thomv\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Libra\Libra\Controllers\DagboekController.cs:regel 113
       bij lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       bij System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       bij System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       bij System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       bij System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
       bij System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       bij System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       bij System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
       bij System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
       bij System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       bij System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
       bij System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
  InnerException:
```

RandomString:

```
create or replace FUNCTION RANDOMSTRING(
  CodeLength NUMBER
) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
BEGIN
    RETURN DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('a', CodeLength);
END RANDOMSTRING;
```

Comment: What's the code in `RANDOMSTRING`?

Comment: It returns a random character string of x characters long: create or replace FUNCTION RANDOMSTRING(
  CodeLength NUMBER
) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
BEGIN
    RETURN DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('a', CodeLength);
END RANDOMSTRING;

Comment: I added it to the previous comment aswell as the actual post.

Comment: However I tested the database code from SQL Developer and it works just fine. It does exactly what it's supposed to do.

Comment: The error thrown says that the Oracle exception is generated by DBMS_RANDOM.STRING function. Only variable in that call is CodeLength so I suggest to add a log inside the function for saving the actual value of CodeLength and see if it is correct. I noticed that if you call the function with CodeLenght set to NULL you get exactly ORA-06502 error

Comment: You are right. CodeLength is actually null as soon as it reaches the function. Gonna find why it is null. If I can't find it I might aswell hard code the length in the function itself. I don't think I'm gonna use different lengths of codes either.

Comment: I think I solved it right now. I took out the second parameter and found out that UserID actually turned into NULL and it wouldn't even insert the row. So I tried to to switch the order between the return parameter and the first input parameter and it worked. Now I added the codeLength back into the system and it works just fine. So I think it is required to declare the return parameter first. I have no idea why though. Thanks for your help.